# connecting two pcs on two routers connected (wan to lan)

Tags: networking, router

Two routers in two separate buildings are connected (lan to wan).
need to connect pc1 and pc2 with each other for remote desktop and file sharing.
but both pcs cant see each other as they are on different ip subnets.
both are TPlink routers and have tried advanced routing in router but i cannot understand what i am doing wrong.
These two buildings have their own internet connection.
picture is my current setup.
[network picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eAN4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should better try to configure VPN. If not, you should make great efforts to route traffic from one pc to another.
Anyway you should post your routes on each router in oredr we could help what you are doing wrong.